# Странная ошибка при компиляции Angular проекта

Tags: angular2, node-modules, angular-cli

Создал `Angular` проект на ноутбуке, там все было окей. Клонировал репозиторий на компьютер, выдает ошибку при компиляции.

```
Date: 2018-04-10T20:53:16.063Z
Hash: 2e73d90cdeedb182dde2
Time: 2280ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.91 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 577 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 372 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 852 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in Could not resolve module E:/C

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Обновил версию `Angular CLI`, удалил папку `node_modules` и установил заново, но ничего не помогло. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой ошибкой, как ее пофиксить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка решена. В пути к проекту был символ `#`, когда его удалил все заработало.